# Xamarin Forms Center items in listview vertically

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have ListView here and I can't get the items to center vertically:

```
<ListView x:Name="TasksList" ItemSelected="TasksList_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding name}" Padding="20, 0, 0, 0"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding status}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Padding="0,0,20,0" TextColor="{Binding statusColor}"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I have tried adding a StackLayout around my labels and played with VericalOptions and VerticalTextOptions, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following code for your Grid in your ListView:

```
 VerticalOptions="Center"
```

Please refer to the following code:

```
    <ListView  x:Name="lstView" RowHeight="60">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding name}" Padding="20, 0, 0, 0"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding status}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Padding="0,0,20,0" ></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I created a demo according to your code, the result is:
[image]